# Получить серийный номер ПК в буфер обмена

Tags: windows, cmd, консоль, администрирование, командная-строка

Серийный номер использую для имени компьютера. Фирма-производитель всегда один, поэтому удобно. Чтобы каждый раз не искать серийный номер и не печатать его вручную, использовал команду:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Результат выполнения команды выделил мышкой и вставил куда надо.
Потом догадался положить эту команду в бат-файл:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
Pause
```

Стало еще удобнее. Батник лежит на флешке с виндовс, всегда под рукой.
Погуглив про буфер обмена наткнулся на команду **CLIP**. Теперь батник выглядит так:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber | clip
```

Теперь результат команды сразу ложится в буфер обмена, а это уже почти похожу на сказку, согласны? :)
К сожалению в буфер ложиться весь вывод команды, а не только серийный номер. Это хоть и очень удобно, но не идеально :( После нескольких попыток понял что не могу сформулировать поисковый запрос чтобы решить проблему.

Сейчас буфер обмена выглядит так:

```
SerialNumber  

61Z8L32
```

Подскажите, как его очистить от всего лишнего и оставить только 7-символов серийного номера компьютера?

Comment: `FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /VALUE') do echo %i`

Comment: Что-то этот ответ мне не помог(

Comment: я серийный номер проверить не могу, но `@FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('wmic bios get ReleaseDate /VALUE') do @echo %i | clip` оставляет время биоса

Comment: Да, этот вариант работает из командной строки, а когда в батник ее пишу - не работает

Comment: А почему именно в буфер? Какую цель ты преследуешь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналог линуксового `grep -v`:

`wmic bios get serialnumber | findstr /V SerialNumber | clip`